# GCP VPC SC No Matching Access Level for FetchUserPreference Method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a service perimeter created included many services including "logging.googleapis.com".

As per the Logs I can see a VPC SC Error with below info,

```
authenticationInfo: { }  --> Empty
ingressViolations: [0: {
servicePerimeter: "accessPolicies/<number>/servicePerimeters/<name>"
targetResource: "projects/<number>"}]
resourceNames: [0: "projects/<Name>/locations/global"]
methodName: "google.logging.v2.ConfigServiceV2.FetchUserPreference"
serviceName: "logging.googleapis.com"
```

As you can see, there is no auth email present and neither any source information as in the source project.
The target project is in scope of the Service Perimeter.
The method name is FetchUserPreference which I didn't find online as a valid method.

Any idea on what could have generated this request and how to resolve this error?